# await multiple futures crashes with Future.wait()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I have created a test case for signout method:

```
test('when user signs out current signin providers should sign out',
      () async {
    final _ = await authFacade.signOut();
    verify(mockGoogleSignin.signOut()).called(1);
    verify(mockFirebaseAuth.signOut()).called(1);
  });
```

and here is implementation in `AuthFacade`

```
Future<void> signOut() => Future.wait(
        [_googleSignIn.signOut(), _firebaseAuth.signOut()],
      );
```

when I run the test it fails:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'then' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: then<Null>(Closure: (void) => Null, onError: Closure: (Object, StackTrace) => Null)
dart:async                                                              Future.wait
package:flutter_ddd/infrastructure/auth/firbase_auth_facade.dart 87:36  FirebaseAuthFacade.signOut
test/infrastructure/auth/firebase_auth_facade_test.dart 194:32          main.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                                              Future.wait
package:flutter_ddd/infrastructure/auth/firbase_auth_facade.dart 87:36  FirebaseAuthFacade.signOut
test/infrastructure/auth/firebase_auth_facade_test.dart 194:32          main.<fn>
✖ when user signs out current signin providers should sign out
Exited (1)
```

by changing implementation to this it passes:

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  }
```

[image]

any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: post line #194 of `firebase_auth_facade_test.dart`

Comment: @pskink its `final _ = await authFacade.signOut();` which is pasted in top of the question

Comment: @pskink I have updated the question with an screenshot

Comment: `final future = authFacade.signOut(); print('future: $future'); final _ = await future;` - what do you see in the logs now? `future: null`?

Comment: same error, and future is absolutely not null: `future: Instance of 'Future<List<void>>'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217654/discussion-between-hashem-aboonajmi-and-pskink).